# codeigniter - how to easily catch PDO Exception/error w/o modifying the pdo_driver file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo, codeigniter-2

I'm using codeigniter with PDO. It works fine, however I'm not happy that in pdo_driver (ie. in system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php) the error mode is set to silent.

ie.

```
$this->options['PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE'] = PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT;
```

by setting the error mode to silent I can't catch any PDOException (I have also tried errorInfo() and got nothing)

`I do not want to directly change the pdo_driver file`, db class doesn't seem to be extendable, so anyone knows the way of getting the error?

please advise.

Comment: I have no idea of codeigniter, can't you use `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` after establishing the connection?

Comment: You *can* extend the db class: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

Comment: oh I didn't know that I could extend the db class as I can't find any info in the documentation. thanks